# AngularJS continuous task across all pages

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an 'external'-AJAX heavy site which requires that AJAX requests be made in sequence whilst the user is active on the website. So, let's say there are 50 unique requests to be performed; then whilst a user is on the website these requests will need to be iterated over (and the user updated on the progress i.e. 4/50 complete) regardless of any page changes and things.

How is it achieved in AngularJS that some task is run continuously throughout the web user's visit? I'm thinking it might be through Services but looking for some better knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a controller that is only responsible for the 50 requests. The controller can be bound to the view and could update a progress bar there.

How you make your calls depends primarily if they have to be synchronous or can be done in parallel. Just make calls to a service that does the ajax calls and track which one of the calls is already finished.